# Pascal abc, assign

Tags: pascal, файлы

```
program test;
var
  myfile: text;
begin
  assign(myfile, "test1.txt");//Здесь ошибка
  close(myfile);
end.
```

Текст ошибки: "Ошибка: неверное выражение".
Pascal abc, в интернете ничего не нашёл.
Помогите :(

Comment: Если ви не знаете как работать с файлами или вам трудно можете [заглянуть сюда][1]


  [1]: http://abramov.org.ua/ru/category/opp/fajly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался. Нужны не двойные кавычки, а обычные. Т.е. 'test1.txt'

Answer (score 1):

Не верное определение типа

```
var
  myfile: text;
```

Должно быть **textfile**